# php equivalent of this html onload

Tags: php, html, onload, equivalent

```
echo '
<body onload="document.subfrm.submit()">
        <form method=post action="index.php?" name="subfrm">
<input type=hidden name="mnux" value="master.dosen">
<input type=hidden name="gos" value="DsnEdt">
<input type=hidden name="md" value="0">
<input type=hidden name="dsnid" value="'.$dsncr.'">

</form>
    </body>
    <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=JavascriptHarusDinyalakan.html" /></noscript>
    <noscript><p>Please enable JavaScript in your browser for better use of the website.</p></noscript>
';
```

i tried both method here http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-submit.html
but none of them redirected to new page

Comment: im belive you need to use document.getElementByName('subfrm')[0] in the body onload

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
        {
            $params = array('http' => array(
                            'method' => 'POST',
                            'content' => $data
                        ));
            if($optional_headers != null)
            {
                $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
            }
            $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
            $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
            if (!$fp)
            {
                throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
            }
            $response='';
            while (!feof($fp))
            {
                $response = $response.fgets($fp);
            }
            if ($response === false)
            {
                throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
            }

            fclose($fp);
            return $response;
        }
        $host = 'http://mydomain.in';
        $url = 'http://mydomain.in/formHandler.php';
        $username = 'admin';
        $password = '123456';
        $data = array ('action' => 'login','lgname' => $username, 'lgpassword' => $password, 'format' => 'txt');
        $data = http_build_query($data);
        $reply = do_post_request($url, $data);
        echo "**********Response*********<pre>";
        echo var_dump($reply);
        #header('location:'.$host);
        #exit;

       } 
else {
   echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"><input type="text" name="uname" /><br><input type="password" name="password" /><input type="submit" name="submit"></form>';

       }

     ?>
```

Comment: is this make form data not visible via view-source etc in browser?

Comment: still not redirected